# How does z%x==0 or y%z==0 imply the logic of the chicken farm question?

Tags: java, logic

In Chefland, each chicken has X legs and each duck has Y legs. Chef's farm can have exactly one type of bird.

Given that the birds on the farm have a total of Z legs:

Print CHICKEN, if the farm can have only chickens but not ducks.|
Print DUCK, if the farm can have only ducks but not chickens.|
Print ANY, if the farm can have either chickens or ducks.|
Print NONE, if the farm can have neither chickens nor ducks.

Sample Input 1:
3 ->
2 3 5,
2 2 2,
3 4 6

Sample Output 1:
NONE,
ANY,
CHICKEN

**Can anyone explain this question in laymen's term or in a simplified term ??...through the solution of others it says check if z%x==0 but how ??....what makes it to check for the modulus**

Comment: `z % x == 0` means that `z` is evenly divisible by `x`, which means the farm can have exactly `z / x` chickens.

Comment: If either ducks or chickens can only have 1 leg, it falls over

Comment: On a serious note, you sure that the question says `y%z ==0`?

Comment: yes as per the problem solving logic Y%Z==0 will tell about the ducks